# CustomSortOrder for Taxonomy Term (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

I'm trying to set a custom order for my term set "Cities" using the Term store management tool.

When the user creates a new content type which has the column "City", the cities from the term store are displayed in the correct order. But when I'm looking at the term store from code, the order is not correct at all. To get the term set I'm using this:

```
 TermCollection myTermCollection = term.Groups[taxonomyGroupName].TermSets[taxonomyListName].GetAllTerms();
```

The default order in the 'myTermCollection' is the creation order of the taxonomies. The order listed in the property "CustomSortOrder" is alphabeticall. None of them are the correct one set using the term store management tool.

I ran manually the Taxonomy Update Scheduler, and the job works fine since I saw taxonomy names being updated correctly after running this, but the order is still not right.

Any ideas are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple!

In order to get the custom order, I was doing:

```
TermCollection myTermCollection = term.Groups[taxonomyGroupName].TermSets[taxonomyListName].GetAllTerms();
orderList = myTermCollection[0].CustomSortOrder;
```

Instead, I had to do

```
TermCollection myTermCollection = term.Groups[taxonomyGroupName].TermSets[taxonomyListName].GetAllTerms();
orderList = myTermCollection[0].TermSet.CustomSortOrder;
```

I'm not sure for what myTermCollection[0].CustomSortOrder stands for, but it's not what I need. What I need is myTermCollection[0].TermSet.CustomSortOrder.